# Trouble with Restrict to Single Folder and Upload Location

Tags: assets

I have a Matrix field with two blocks. Each block has an assets field that I'm trying to set to restrict to uploads to a single folder and setting the upload location to {slug}. Basically what I'm trying to do is set up a main folder for my portfolio. I want to be able to upload images for each entry and have them placed in a folder with the same name as the entry so whenI look in Assets I see something like:

```
Portfolio
-- project 1 entry name
-- project 2 entry name
...
-- project 17 entry name
-- project 18 entry name
```

When I upload the file in my entry form no subfolders are created. I have tried a few things to remedy the problem to no avail. I've set permissions to 777 and have tried placing a / before {slug} because the fileSystemPath variable doesn't have a trailing slash in my general.php config file. Any other issues that might cause this?

Comment: Stuart, I'm not at all certain you can evaluate {slug} at that point. Especially not if you're uploading from the CP. I suggested elsewhere about assuring a full file system path, but by your naming it appears you've done that. Maybe if you explain a little more specifically what you're doing, one of us can give an idea. Or you'll make it easier for the travelling duo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're inside the context of a Matrix block, you'll want to use:

```
{owner.slug}
```

instead of:

```
{slug}
```

More information on that http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths

Comment: This makes sense but I would have never thought this was necessary. Are there instances where the slug isn't referencing the parent?

Comment: Sure... when it's not inside of Matrix. :)